# Measure horizontal plane surface ARKIT

Tags: ios, arkit

How to measure horizontal plane surface using ARKit Scenekit before placing objects? I want to have a model of the room before placing objects. Thanks in advance!

Comment: take the time to search on google

Comment: i did..but i haven`t found any help to my problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing the size of a room in advance is tricky...

Measuring the size of any detected planes however isn’t:

Each time a Horizontal or Vertical surface is detected (assuming you have them enabled), an ARPlaneAnchor is generated:

> When you run a world-tracking AR session whose planeDetection option is enabled, the session automatically adds to its list of anchors an ARPlaneAnchor object for each flat surface ARKit detects with the back-facing camera. Each plane anchor provides information about the estimated position and shape of the surface.

This is called in the following delegate callback:

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) { }
```

You can get the width of the ARPlaneAnchor therefore, like so:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. Get The Current ARPlaneAnchor
        guard let anchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

        //2. Log The Initial Width & Height
        print("""
            Initial Width = \(anchor.extent.x)
            Initial Height = \(anchor.extent.z)
            """)

 }
```

There is one issue with this initial solution however, in that an ARPlaneAnchor gets updated (e.g. it's size changes) via the the following callback:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) { }
```

As such if you want to track the updated size of an `ARPlaneAnchor` you need take this into consideration.

Let's look at how this could be done:

First we create our own `SCNNode Subclass` called PlaneNode, which will return the size of the plane even when updated.

Please note that you don’t need to create a subclass to achieve the same results, although I have in order that it can be  easily reused:

```
    class PlaneNode: SCNNode {

    let DEFAULT_IMAGE: String = "defaultGrid"
    let NAME: String = "PlaneNode"
    var planeGeometry: SCNPlane
    var planeAnchor: ARPlaneAnchor

    var widthInfo: String!
    var heightInfo: String!
    var alignmentInfo: String!

    //---------------
    //MARK: LifeCycle
    //---------------

    /// Inititialization
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - anchor: ARPlaneAnchor
    ///   - node: SCNNode
    ///   - node: Bool
    init(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor, node: SCNNode, image: Bool, identifier: Int, opacity: CGFloat = 0.25){

        //1. Create The SCNPlaneGeometry
        self.planeAnchor = anchor
        self.planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(anchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(anchor.extent.z))
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)

        super.init()

        //2. If The Image Bool Is True We Use The Default Image From The Assets Bundle
        let planeMaterial = SCNMaterial()

        if image{

            planeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: DEFAULT_IMAGE)

        }else{

            planeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
        }

        //3. Set The Geometries Contents
        self.planeGeometry.materials = [planeMaterial]

        //4. Set The Position Of The PlaneNode
        planeNode.simdPosition = float3(self.planeAnchor.center.x, 0, self.planeAnchor.center.z)

        //5. Rotate It On It's XAxis
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

        //6. Set The Opacity Of The Node
        planeNode.opacity = opacity

        //7. Add The PlaneNode
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)

        //8. Set The Nodes ID
        node.name = "\(NAME) \(identifier)"

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }


    /// Updates The Size Of The Plane As & When The ARPlaneAnchor Has Been Updated
    ///
    /// - Parameter anchor: ARPlaneAnchor
    func update(_ anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {

        self.planeAnchor = anchor

        self.planeGeometry.width = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x)
        self.planeGeometry.height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z)

        self.position = SCNVector3Make(anchor.center.x, 0.01, anchor.center.z)

        returnPlaneInfo()
    }

    //-----------------------
    //MARK: Plane Information
    //-----------------------

    /// Returns The Size Of The ARPlaneAnchor & Its Alignment
    func returnPlaneInfo(){

        let widthOfPlane = self.planeAnchor.extent.x
        let heightOfPlane = self.planeAnchor.extent.z

        var planeAlignment: String!

        switch planeAnchor.alignment {

        case .horizontal:
            planeAlignment = "Horizontal"
        case .vertical:
            planeAlignment = "Vertical"
        }

        #if DEBUG
        print("""
            Width Of Plane =  \(String(format: "%.2fm", widthOfPlane))
            Height Of Plane =  \(String(format: "%.2fm", heightOfPlane))
            Plane Alignment = \(planeAlignment)
            """)
        #endif

        self.widthInfo = String(format: "%.2fm", widthOfPlane)
        self.heightInfo = String(format: "%.2fm", heightOfPlane)
        self.alignmentInfo = planeAlignment
      }

    }
```

Having created our subclass we then need to use it within our `ViewController`. You will normally get more than one `ARPlaneAnchor`, however in this example we just assume there will be one.

So we will create a variable which will reference our PlaneNode:

```
var planeNode:PlaneNode?
```

Then in the ARSCNViewDelegate we will create our PlaneNode like so:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    //1. Get The Current ARPlaneAnchor
    guard let anchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

    //2. Create The PlaneNode
    if planeNode == nil{
        planeNode = PlaneNode(anchor: anchor, node: node, image: true, identifier: 0, opacity: 1)
        node.addChildNode(planeNode!)
        planeNode?.name = String("Detected Plane")
    }

}
```

Then all you need to do is track the updating of the PlaneNode e.g:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        guard let anchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor, let existingPlane = planeNode else { return }
        existingPlane.update(anchor)
}
```

If all goes according to plan you should see something like this in your `consoleLog:`

*Width Of Plane =  0.07m*

*Height Of Plane =  0.15m*

*Plane Alignment = Optional("Horizontal")*

Hopefully this is more than enough to get you started...